# Unable to enter text in angular text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am using the below input text box tag in 2 different templates.

```
<div class="text-input">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="">
</div>
```

In the first template i am able to enter text. But when i change the view to the second template, i am unable to enter text in the text box. Again when i go back to the first template, I am not able to enter text.

I have noticed in the console that both the text box are in the below state initially (before clicking in the text box to enter text):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" id="" placeholder="" style="">
```

When text entering is possible, the class is updated to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" id="" placeholder="" >
```

There is no change in class when it is disabled.

What is the possible problem and how can i fix this?

Edits :

```
<form class="view-tools ">
   <ng-include src="'views/view1.tpl.html'"></ng-include>
</form>

<form class="view-tools ">
   <ng-include src="'views/view2.tpl.html'"></ng-include>
</form>
```

i have a function in the controller which basically sets scope variables to true or false to show/hide the views.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker that reproduce the issue?

Comment: @varit05 the problem is this is a part of a big application and a lot of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding both a *required* and a *ng-model* to your inputs.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="thisInput" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" required>
```

See if that fixes it

Comment: can you show how you are transitioning between your views/templates?